# Is it possible to Send SMS from Flutter without a SIM card?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to figure out how to send a SMS from Flutter without using a SIM CARD.
I have a list of contacts followed by the password of each user stored in two seperated Columns in Excel sheet, I'm trying to read these contact in flutter than send the password of each user via SMS services.
Almost every plugin requires a SIM card, but my app would be so much better if its a desktop app.

Thank you.

Comment: Mate, you can't use SMS services without a SIM card...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a service like [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com) to set up a phone number that can be used to send texts. This works by interfacing with the Twilio API over the internet to send your request (what number you want to text, and what the sms content should be, etc) and then Twilio will send the corresponding text message.

Answer (score 0):

Email a Text
Another method, albeit clunkier compared to the others in this article, is to send a text message via email. Each wireless carrier has an email formula for doing so. For example, to send a text message (SMS) to an AT&T user, email "number@txt.att.net," but replace "number" with a 10-digit phone number. To send an MMS (multimedia message, such as a photo) email "number@mms.att.net." Check with the carrier or reference this list of carrier email addresses.

The issue here is the email could end up in the recipients' spam folder or get lost in the shuffle since it will look differently from standard email addresses. You must also know which carrier the recipient uses.

https://20somethingfinance.com/how-to-send-text-messages-sms-via-email-for-free/